# Тире или двоеточие. В чём смысловая разница?

Tags: тире-или-двоеточие

В чём смысловая разница в вариантах предложения? Оба варианта верны:

1. Наличие бытовой техники: чайника, холодильника, телевизора.
2. Наличие бытовой техники — чайника, холодильника, телевизора.

Answer (score 1):

1.*Наличие бытовой техники: чайника, холодильника, телевизора*.
Двоеточие после обобщающего слова предупреждает, что дальше перечисляются элементы бытовой техники.

2.*Наличие бытовой техники — чайника, холодильника, телевизора.* Тире отделяет однородные приложения в конце предложения, при этом однородный ряд **имеет уточняющий характер**

Answer (score 1):

В подобных вариантах  меняется **значимость** обобщающего слова и однородного ряда.

В первом случае **смысловым центром** является однородный ряд, где перечисляются  **конкретные** предметы.

Во втором случае подчеркивается важность наличия **бытовой техники в общем**,  однородный же ряд имеет присоединительное значение.